# How do I change strings based on some rules?

Tags: python, string

I have following texts, each line has two phrases and separated with `"\t"`

```
RoadTunnel    RouteOfTransportation
LaunchPad   Infrastructure
CyclingLeague   SportsLeague
Territory   PopulatedPlace
CurlingLeague   SportsLeague
GatedCommunity  PopulatedPlace
```

What I want to get is to add `_` to separate words, the results should be:

```
Road_Tunnel    Route_Of_Transportation
Launch_Pad  Infrastructure
Cycling_League  Sports_League
Territory   Populated_Place
Curling_League  Sports_League
Gated_Community Populated_Place
```

There is no cases such as `"ABTest"` or `"aBTest"`, and there are cases such as three words together `"RouteOfTransportation"` I tried several ways but not succeeded.

One of my tries is:

```
textProcessed = re.sub(r"([A-Z][a-z]+)(?=([A-Z][a-z]+))", r"\1_", text)
```

But there is no result

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Btw. I think additional test cases would be nice. What should `HTTPResponse` or `CSV` be converted to?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @Rogalski, I should have put my codes in my question. I will pay attention next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression and `re.sub`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''LaunchPad   Infrastructure
... CyclingLeague   SportsLeague
... Territory   PopulatedPlace
... CurlingLeague   SportsLeague
... GatedCommunity  PopulatedPlace'''
>>> subbed = re.sub('([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s)
>>> print(subbed)
Launch_Pad   Infrastructure
Cycling_League   Sports_League
Territory   Populated_Place
Curling_League   Sports_League
Gated_Community  Populated_Place
```

edit: Here's another one, since your test cases don't cover enough to be sure what exactly you want:

```
>>> re.sub('([a-zA-Z])([A-Z])([a-z])', r'\1_\2\3', 'ABThingThing')
'AB_Thing_Thing'
```

Comment: I would replace `([A-Z][a-z]+)` by `([a-zA-Z])` though so that patterns like `"BThing"` works. Note that it won't support patterns like `"ABThing"`.

Comment: @QuentinRoy yeah, we currently don't know what the intended behavior for "BThing" would even be. Does OP consider "BT" a word? Anyway, thanks for the comment, based on OP's actual specs he can now choose the correct regex, or adjust it on its own.

Comment: @timgeb, sorry for the ambiguity, I have modified my question

Answer (score 2):

Combining `re.findall` and `str.join`:

```
>>> "_".join(re.findall(r"[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]*", text))
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, a slightly different solution can be this:

```
import re
result = re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z])", r"\1_", s)
```

It will insert a `_` before any upper case letter that follows another letter (whether it is upper or lower case).

- `"TheRabbit IsBlue"` => `"The_Rabbit Is_Blue"`
- `"ABThing ThingAB"` => `"A_B_Thing Thing_A_B"`

It does not support special chars.